# Why does the model fail to learn this game of filling up integers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

Why does my model fail to learn to play this game of just producing an array of unique elements from 1 to 5 from a partially filled array?

===

I am trying to train a model to perform this task:

**Given a fixed array of 5 elements consisting of at most ONE of each element from (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and ONE OR MORE (0), replace the 0s with appropriate values so that the final array has exactly ONE of each (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).**

So, here is how it should be played:

- [1, 2, 3, 4, 0] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
- [4, 3, 0, 5, 1] => [4, 3, 2, 5, 1]
- [0, 3, 5, 4, 0] => [2, 3, 5, 4, 1] OR [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
- ...

This is not a complicated game (in human sense), but I want to see if a model can identify the rules (replace 0s with 1 to 5, so that final array has only exactly one element from (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).

The way I did this is:

- Generate N examples of combinations configurations with elements of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as answers, and randomly replace some of the elements as 0s.
- For instance, one training example is [(0, 3, 5, 4, 0), (2, 3, 5, 4, 1)].
- There can be multiple same input mapping to different output, i.e. [(0, 3, 5, 4, 0), (2, 3, 5, 4, 1)] and [(0, 3, 5, 4, 0), (1, 3, 5, 4, 2)] can be both present as two separate training instances.
- Separate the training data set 10 fold, shuffled, and train using a RandomForestClassifier from Scikit-Learn.
- A correct output is defined as the final configuration array has exactly ONE element from (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). So (2, 4, 4, 5, 1) is not valid.

===

Surprisingly, using 1000, 10000, 50000, and even 100000 training examples still results in the model only getting ~70% of the test cases right - meaning the model did not learn how to play the game with increasing training examples.

One thing I was thinking is that RandomForestClassifier is just not used for this type of problem, called structured machine learning, where the output is not a single category or a real-valued output, but a vector of output.

More questions:

- Why does the model fail to learn this
  game?
- Is this the right way to model
  this problem?
- Is the data not enough
  to learn this task? But increasing
  data from 1000 to 100000 does not
  seem to help at all.

Comment: Thanks lejlot and jakevdp for the detailed explanations. My original motivation was to write up a model to see if it can solve Sudoku, but I figured I could try a simpler game (ah yes, I know we can solve it using search). I really thought it should work, but this is interesting to know where it works/doesn't work. I would love to vote both as answers but I'll have to take the lengthier one (which I believe future readers may get more insight), but really thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lejlot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33736328/2937831) is excellent, but I thought I'd add a bit of intuition as to *why* random forest fails in this case.

You have to keep in mind that Machine Learning isn't some magic way to impart intelligence to computers; it's simply a way of fitting a particular model to your data and using that model to make generalizations. As the old adage goes, "all models are wrong, but some are useful". You've hit on a case where the model is wrong as usual, but also happens to be useless!

- **The output space**: Random forests at their core are basically a clever and generalizable way of mapping inputs to outputs. Your output space has `5^5 = 3125` possible unique outputs, and only `5! = 120` of these are valid (i.e. outputs with one of each number). The only way for a random forest to know whether an output is valid is if it has seen it: so in order to work correctly, **your training set will have to include examples with all of those 120 outputs.**
- **The input space**: when a random forest encounters an input it has seen before, it will map that directly to an output that it has seen before. But what if it encounters an input it has not seen? For example, what if you ask for the answer to `[0, 2, 3, 4, 1]` and this is not in the training set? In terms of Euclidean distance (a useful way to think about how things are grouped) the closest result will probably be something like `[0, 2, 3, 4, 0]`, which might map to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which is wrong. Thus we see that in order for random forests to work correctly, **your training set will have to have all possible inputs**. Some quick combinatorics show that your training set will have to be of size at least `5!*32 = 3840`, with no duplicates.
- **The forest itself**: even if you have a complete input space, the random forest does not consist of a simple dictionary mapping of inputs to outputs. Depending on the parameters of the model, the mapping is typically from groups of *nearby results* to a single answer, so that, for example, `{[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]...}` will all map to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. This sort of generalization is useful in most cases, but is not useful for your particular problem. The only way for the random forest to work in your case would be to push the `max_depth` and `min_samples` parameters to their extreme values, so that the forest is essentially a one-to-one mapping of inputs to their correct outputs: in other words your classifier would be just an extremely complicated way of building a dictionary.

To summarize: Machine Learning is just a model applied to data, which is useful in certain cases. In your case, the model is not all that useful: in order for Random Forests to work on your problem, you'd need to over-fit a comprehensive set of inputs and outputs. At that point, you might as well just construct a dictionary and call it a day.

Answer (score 2):

*I do assume that this is just a mind-exercise, and not actual problem, because obviously - set-based solution will be better then any ML technique in such task.*

In short - because classifiers/regressors **are not** for combinatorial optimization. Your problem has extremely strong constraints - only very small number of values are "correct" and "observable", you look for a **property** of the output, and not the **value**. These **is not** setting for classification or regression.

What can you do?

- in such contrained scenario you have to give your method **knowledge** about what is going on. Show it a state space. This is rather a case for simple state-space AI, not for ML as such - rather for any metaoptimizations, like hill climbing, simulated annealing, ga etc.
- look at things like *General Game Playing*, this is somehow similar, but the important difference is that you **provide set of rules**.
- look at things like *Neural Turing Machines*, these are sequential methods trying to learn how to **manipulate the data** instead of classification/regression

In general this is a very common missconception when one tries to learn machine learning. Not every problem is suitable for "just applying" known ML techniques. Most of the problems "out there" require considerable input from researcher to be able to explot the strength of ML.